# Find the longest repeated subsequence of max length N in Python

Tags: python, combinations, subsequence

I have some strings representing the order of events:

`s1 = 'A->B->E->D->A->C->B->D'`

`s2= 'A->B->C->A->B'`

`s3 = 'A->B->A`

In each string I want to find all repeating patterns of max length N.

```
import itertools

def find_all_comb(event_list,max_events):
    all_combs = []
    for j in range(1,max_events+1):
        all_combs.extend(list(set(['->'.join(x) for x in list(itertools.combinations(event_list,j))])))
    return all_combs

def find_repeating_patterns(x):
    split_events = x.split("->")
    all_combs = find_all_comb(split_events,int(len(x)/2))

    repeating_patterns = []
    for comb in all_combs:
        c_split_event = [p for p in split_events if p in comb]
        if '->'.join(c_split_event).count(comb) > 1:
            repeating_patterns.extend([comb])
    output_list = []
    longest_repeating_patterns = [s for s in repeating_patterns if any(set(s).issuperset(set(i)) and len(s) > len(i) for i in repeating_patterns)]
    while output_list != longest_repeating_patterns:
        if longest_repeating_patterns == []:
            break
        output_list = longest_repeating_patterns.copy()
        longest_repeating_patterns = [s for s in longest_repeating_patterns if any(set(s).issuperset(set(i)) and len(s) > len(i) for i in longest_repeating_patterns)]

return output_list
```

For `s1`, this returns the correct pattern `[A,B,D]`, and for `s2`, it returns `[A,B]`. For `s3`, it should return `[A]`, but it returns an empty list. This is because of the line:

```
[s for s in repeating_patterns if any(set(s).issuperset(set(i)) and len(s) > len(i) for i in repeating_patterns)]
```

which does not allow `len(s) > len(i)`.

How would I be able to capture both cases here?

Comment: The requirements seem unclear, since `[A,B,D]` is a *subset* rather than a *subsequence*. Then again, your code does not disregard order, so it isn't a simple subset either.

Comment: @ekhumoro `[A,B,D]` *is* a aubsequence there.

Comment: Added the word "repeating" in the title, that should clear things up hopefully.

Comment: I also have an even more concise requirement in the last line in the post that should clear things up as well.

Comment: Is this really both about sets and about sequences? Not clear how.

Comment: @kspr If you mean strict mathematical subsequences, it makes no sense to talk about sets as well, because sets aren't ordered (i.e. *sequential*).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback, maybe I have been mixing up the terms here? Would you believe that the following title would make more sense "How to filter out all repeating superpatterns from a list of sequences in Python?"?

Comment: I highly doubt [superpattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpattern) is really what you mean.

Comment: @superbrain I think it might be, please see my edit when I go through it in more detail. Would you agree that superpattern is what I mean then?

Comment: I think you just mean "subsequence with length larger than 1" (btw not sure why you disregard subsequences of length 1).

Comment: Thanks for that input, you are right, I should include length 1 as well. See edit now.

Comment: @kspr Surely the title should simply be: "Find the longest repeated subsequence of max length N"? Then explain in the question exactly how this applies to your actual use-case.

Comment: @ekhumoro .. well this is a bit embarassing, thank you for the patience, this indeed seems to be the most simple title that captures what I need. Thanks. Will edit one last time..

Comment: @ekhumoro I'd remove the "of max length N". Unless N is part of the input or gets used somehow.

Comment: it is part of the input, see max_events in all_comb function

Comment: What is best practice here now, should I recreate this post without all this clutter of edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler and more efficient solution:

```
def longest_subsequence(events, limit, sep='->'):
    events = list(enumerate(events.split(sep)))
    output = {}
    seen = {}
    for n in range(limit, 0, -1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(events, n):
            indexes, key = zip(*combination)
            if key in seen:
                if key not in output and seen[key].isdisjoint(indexes):
                    output[key] = sep.join(key)
            else:
                seen[key] = set(indexes)
        if output:
            break
    return list(output.values())
```

This looks at the longest matches first and terminates early if one is found. It eliminates self-overlapping repeated subsequences by saving the indexes of the last match and comparing them with the current candidate.

Demo:

```
samples = (
    'A->B->E->D->A->C->B->D',
    'A->B->C->A->B',
    'A->B->A',
    'A->B->E->D->A->C->B->E->D->A',
    'B->B->B->C->C',
    'A->B->A->B->C->C',
    'A',
    '',
    )

for index, sample in enumerate(samples, 1):
    result = longest_subsequence(sample, 4)
    print('(%s) %r\n%s\n' % (index, sample, result))
```

Output:

```
(1) 'A->B->E->D->A->C->B->D'
['A->B->D']

(2) 'A->B->C->A->B'
['A->B']

(3) 'A->B->A'
['A']

(4) 'A->B->E->D->A->C->B->E->D->A'
['A->B->E->D', 'B->E->D->A']

(5) 'B->B->B->C->C'
['B->C']

(6) 'A->B->A->B->C->C'
['A->B->C']

(7) 'A'
[]

(8) ''
[]
```

Comment: Hi, when giving 'A->B->A->B->C->C' as input, it does only output ['A->B']. So something is not working as expected.

Comment: @kspr Okay - that's easily changed (see my updated answer). This is why I asked you to clarify how overlapping subsequences should be handled. You didn't really do that, so I just added the `B->B->B->C->C` sample and made my output match yours. Note that your current solution is therefore broken for samples 5 & 6 (as numbered in the output above).

Answer (score 0):

Adding one extra line which adds anything that is not a subsequence to any of the sequences in the `output_list` is one solution to this.

```
    import itertools

    def find_all_comb(event_list,max_events):
        all_combs = []
        for j in range(1,max_events+1):
            all_combs.extend(list(set(['->'.join(x) for x in list(itertools.combinations(event_list,j))])))
        return all_combs

    def find_repeating_patterns(x):
        split_events = x.split("->")
        all_combs = find_all_comb(split_events,int(len(x)/2))
        
        repeating_patterns = []
        for comb in all_combs:

            c_split_event = [p for p in split_events if p in comb]
            if '->'.join(c_split_event).count(comb) > 1:
                repeating_patterns.extend([comb])
        output_list = []
        longest_repeating_patterns = [s for s in repeating_patterns if any(set(s).issuperset(set(i)) and len(s) > len(i) for i in repeating_patterns)]
        while output_list != longest_repeating_patterns:
            if longest_repeating_patterns == []:
                break
            output_list = longest_repeating_patterns.copy()
            longest_repeating_patterns = [s for s in longest_repeating_patterns if any(set(s).issuperset(set(i)) and len(s) > len(i) for i in longest_repeating_patterns)]
        output_list.extend([s for s in repeating_patterns if not any(set(i).issuperset(set(s)) for i in output_list)]) <--- ADDED LINE FOR SOLUTION

        return output_list


s1 = A->B->E->D->A->C->B->D
s2 = A->B->C->A->B
s3 = A->B->A

print(find_repeating_patterns(s1))

output: [A->B->D]

print(find_repeating_patterns(s2))

output: [A->B]

print(find_repeating_patterns(s3))

output: [A]
```

Comment: What should be the output for `A->B->E->D->A->C->B->E->D->A`? Your current solution gives `['B->E->D->A', 'A->B->E->D']`, which includes *some* overlapping subsequences, but not all of them. If *all* possibilities are included, the correct output for `s1` would be `['A->B->E->D', 'A->C->B->D']` (since `ABE` and `CBD` can be used twice).

Comment: Hi, the constraint is that one event may not be used in two patterns.

Comment: Not sure if you are still interested, but I have a simpler and more efficient solution which produces the same output as yours.

Comment: Please share, I am definitely still interested.

Comment: Okay - I have now added my alternative solution.